# How to find if this sequence converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus

Given $$a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\times n}{n+n^{1/2}}$$

First used theorem if the limit of $|a_n|$ is $0$ then the limit of $a_n$ is $0$.

this yielded $\frac{2n}{n+\sqrt{n}}$

I tried dividing both sides by $n$ and get

$\frac{2}{1+n^{-(1/2)}}$

Can I assume that this is divergent because I know n should end up on the top even if I don't know exactly how to re-arrange it on top with the $1+$ in the way?

I also tried using l'Hospitals rule but again ended up with a strange result which I don't know how to arrange

$\frac{2}{1+\frac12n^{-1/2}}$

Comment: If $\lim_na_n=a$ and $0\ne b=\lim_n b_n$ then $\lim_n a_n/b_n=a/b.$  Here we have $a_n=2$ and $b_n=1\pm 1/\sqrt n.$

Answer (score 3):

If $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n}{n+n^{1/2}}$ then the limit as $n\to \infty$ of $|a_n|=\frac{n}{n+n^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{1+n^{-1/2}}\to 1$. But the terms of the original sequence are alternate positive and negative, so for large $n$ the terms of the sequence are alternatly close to $+1$ and $-1$, so the sequence does not converge.

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot. does this imply that the only way a sequence that alternates between postive and negative can converge is if the limit is equal to 0?

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon Yes